# Some resizing issues on menu and images

Tags: css, html, resize

For the last few days I have been thinking and working on a website. When playing around with resizing i found out that the site doesn't do such a good job. I think the site should look good from 1024 by 768 and up.

So when resizing the page below to the minium dimension you see the the top menu will get squashed together. Eventhough there would be enough space for all menu items. And also I would like the images to get resized properly to the window size.

Here is the link
http://bit.ly/NpE9cF

Would someone please help me to give me some practical advice?
Should I do the resize work with something like jquery? Or can i fix these issues in css?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In style.css you have some fixed width for `ul#primary li a {}`.

Change this width to some `%` value. And also add some `min-width` so that after certain resize the width will not decrease further.

change

```
ul#primary li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 11px;
    width: 192px;
}
```

to

```
ul#primary li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 20px 20px 11px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

in style.css file.

Comment: looks good, only my call to action button does weird things. It floats to the next line.

Comment: Which is the action button, next and prev??

Comment: you will see them when you hover over the images

Comment: Those buttons are not working properly. And they are blocking the menus. Please check your java script or plug in you are using for those buttons.

Comment: the buttons are plain html / css no scripting. When take them out the behaviour is the same!

Comment: I am not getting what is the problem exactly, now. I can see the buttons. But onclicking on images nothing happens. Also at the right side a part of another image is visible. So please what do you need exactly.

Comment: Hi Rain that's right. Didn't make that functionality yet. But the problem is that by your solution the green button floats to the next line on 1024 * 768 and bigger

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15125/discussion-between-sanders-and-rain)